# I can't get the ionic 2 themes to work, even after replacing the /www folder

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Prerequisites:

1. I have Ionic 2 CLI installed and all the 3 types of templates created.
2. I have tried replacing the /www folder with the theme content.

Even after following the [.Zip](http://docs.usecreator.com/docs/zip-export-an-ionic-project) instructions at the Ionic creater website, there is still no difference when I do `ionic serve --lab`.

If I have created a theme in Ionic creater using the `slider+menu layout` and exported it as `.Zip`, why is it not showing up on the local project even after following the instructions.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ionic Creator supports Ionic 1 project which is based on angular 1, Ionic 2 creates project based on angular 2. Project structure have difference in both Ionic 1 and Ionic 2. I belive this to be reason.

Answer (score 1):

What Nitish has said is correct.

I had the same issue with running themes and projects I created in Ionic Creator. Apparently replacing the /www folder does not work with Ionic2. You need to use Ionic1 for it.

To create an Ionic1 project, use the command

```
ionic start myApp blank --type ionic1
```

Once your project has been created, replace delete all files in /www folder and copy the files/folders in your .zip. Now run

```
ionic serve
```

and your project should be working.

Hope this helps.